# Filtering Files In-Place with Ant?

Tags: ant

I have a directory of files for which I'd like to do "in-place" string filtering using Apache Ant (version 1.7.1 on Linux).

For example, suppose that in directory `mydir` I have files `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`. Further suppose that all occurences of the regular expression `OLD([0-9])` should be changed to `NEW\1`, e.g. `OLD2` → `NEW2`. (Note that the `replace` Ant task won't work because it does not support regular expression filtering.)

This test situation can be created with the following Bash commands (ant will be run in the current directory, i.e. `mydir`'s parent directory):

```
mkdir mydir
for FILE in foo bar baz ; do echo "A OLD1 B OLD2 C OLD3" > mydir/${FILE} ; done
```

Here is my first attempt to do the filtering with Ant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="filter" default="filter">
    <target name="filter">
        <move todir="mydir">
            <fileset dir="mydir"/>
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="OLD([0-9])" replace="NEW\1" flags="g"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </move>
    </target>
</project>
```

Running this first Ant script has no effect on the files in `mydir`. The `overwrite` parameter is `true` by default with the `move` Ant task. I even fiddled with the `granularity` setting, but that didn't help.

Here's my second attempt, which "works," but is slightly annoying because of temporary file creation. This version filters the content properly by moving the content to files with a `filtered` suffix, then the filtered content is "moved back" with original filenames:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="filter" default="filter">
    <target name="filter">
        <move todir="mydir">
            <globmapper from="*" to="*.filtered"/>
            <fileset dir="mydir"/>
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="OLD([0-9])" replace="NEW\1" flags="g"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </move>
        <move todir="mydir">
            <globmapper from="*.filtered" to="*"/>
            <fileset dir="mydir"/>
        </move>
    </target>
</project>
```

**Can the first attempt (without temporary files) be made to work?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task:

```
<replace 
   dir="mydir" 
   includes="foo, bar, baz">
   <replacefilter token="OLD" value="NEW" />
</replace>
```

or the [replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task:

```
<replaceregexp
    file="${src}/build.properties"
    match="OldProperty=(.*)"
    replace="NewProperty=\1"
    byline="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out that my question is incomplete. I "simplified" my production code too much when I wrote this question. I neglected to specify the need for regular expression filtering, which replace does not appear to support (please correct me if I'm wrong!). You've given a great answer for the case without the need for regular expresssions.

Comment: In that case, see the optional replaceregexp task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/OptionalTasks/replaceregexp.html

Comment: The optional tasks! Genius! I've probably looked through the Ant optional tasks twice in my life. Totally forgot they were there. Thanks! Please add a new answer using the replaceregexp task, or edit this answer and I'll accept it. Here, I'll make it easy for you (notice the flags="g" to catch all occurrences):

<replaceregexp match="OLD([0-9])" replace="NEW\1" flags="g">
    <fileset dir="mydir"/>
</replaceregexp>