# Ant script to find a particular string in files under directories/subdirectories and replace with another string

Tags: jenkins, ant, build.xml

I am working on ant script where I need to do the following task:

1) Find a particular string e.g: "cmprod5spt.newton.com" in number
        of jenkin jobs files.
  2) Replace this string with new string for e.g. "cmstar.health.com" in all files.

The location could be different for each server so one of my server the location for all config.xml files are below.In all below files I need to perform above two steps.

/shareddisk/jenkins/var_lib*/jobs/*/config.xml

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src" /> <property name="search.string" value="BAD" />

<fileset id="existing" dir="${src.dir}">
    <patternset id="files">
        <!-- includes/excludes for your source here -->
    </patternset> </fileset>

<fileset id="matches" dir="${src.dir}">
    <patternset refid="files" />
    <contains text="${search.string}" /> </fileset>

<fail message="Found '${search.string}' in one or more files in '${src.dir}'">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount when="greater" count="0" refid="matches" />
    </condition> </fail>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Files In-Place with Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779064/filtering-files-in-place-with-ant)

Comment: Why use ant for this task?

Comment: We are using ant as a our build tool

Comment: @user1513848 And the point made is why do this replacement during the build and not just edit the source code files? If you are generating source code you'd be better advised to look at some sort of template engine that could perform the desired substitution for you in a cleaner manner.